# How to improve step count accuracy, using CMPedometer and HealthKit together

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am integrating health kit in one of my watch application. I wanted to fetch step count using HealthKit in realtime in a time interval. But after reading and understanding, I came to know that realtime is not possible.

My actual goal was to get step counts using health kit in a time period.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is use `CMPedometer` data for displaying real time step count and `HealthKit` to display a more accurate history of step counts. You could run a `HKStatisticsQuery` or `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` to get the aggregated pedometer count (it contains both the steps counted on the user's iPhone and Watch) let's say every hour or maybe just once a day depending on how precise you want to be and only use `CMPedometer` data between `HealthKit` queries.

Using this approach, you will be able to show real time step count to your user, but you will also be able to show a more precise historical summary.

For more information and sample code, see the [official documentation of HKStatisticsQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsquery).